# Can a JavaScript function refer to the prototype on the prototype chain that it was called from?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

```
Constructor1=function(){};
Constructor1.prototype.function1=function this_function()
{
  // Suppose this function was called by the lines after this code block
  // this_function - this function
  // this - the object that this function was called from, i.e. object1
  // ??? - the prototype that this function is in, i.e. Constructor1.prototype
}
Constructor2=function(){};
Constructor2.prototype=Object.create(Constructor1.prototype);
Constructor2.prototype.constructor=Constructor2;
object1=new Constructor2();
object1.function1();
```

How do I retrieve the last reference (indicated by ???) without knowing the name of the constructor?

For instance, say I had an object which inherits from a chain of prototypes. Can I know which prototype is used when I call a method on it?

Both seem theoretically possible, but I can't find any way that works without more than constant number of assignment statements (if I have many such functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prototype of each function has a reference back to the function via the [`constructor` property *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). So you can get the constructor function via

```
var Constr = this.constructor;
```

Getting the prototype is a bit trickier. In browsers supporting ECMAScript 5, you can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf):

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
```

In older browser it *might* be possible to get it via the **non-standard** [`__proto__` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) property:

```
var proto = this.__proto__;
```

---

> Can I know which prototype is used when I call a method on it?

Yes, if the browser supports ES5. Then you have to repeatedly call `Object.getPrototypeOf()` until you find the object with that property. For example:

```
function get_prototype_containing(object, property) {
    do {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            break;
        }
        object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
    }
    while(object.constructor !== window.Object);

    // `object` is the prototype that contains `property`
    return object;
}

// somewhere else
var proto = get_prototype_containing(this, 'function1');
```

Comment: Hmm that's somewhat like doing what the browser already was doing, so I'm surprised there's no better way... Also, how would you find out what was the `???` that I originally wanted? Is it like that? `get_prototype_containing(this,this_function.toString().substring("function ".length,this_function.toString().indexOf("(")))`?

Comment: Because the JavaScript interpreter already has to figure out the first prototype up the chain that contains that method...?

Comment: You have to pass the name of the property the function is assigned. Using the function's name won't work. And yes, the JavaScript interpreter has to do this, but the standard does not define a way to use this functionality from user script. That's just how it is...

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake... I forgot that it will evaluate to "this_function" and not the property name... I guess there's no elegant solution then. I might as well set a property (say "owner") of the function to the prototype then. Then I can use `this_function.owner` to get it.

Comment: Yes, you could wrap your prototype function definition process into another function which takes care of all that.